How to make a plane turn into a pyramid-like shape (with subtle edge rather than a very smooth edge) when using Proportional Editing
I am using Blender 4.1, and I have been following a tutorial regarding Proportional Editing. From the tutorial, it shows a subtle edge when it is transformed. But when I try the same thing, it only shows a very smooth version.
I want to know if there any setting to create a subtle edge when transforming a plane using proportional editing: Linear.

It is sometimes easy to explain why it doesn't work as expected if you just check which Blender version is used in a tutorial. The behaviour in the tutorial is from a much older version and only appearing if you used Connected Only (which you do not either in your screenshot) - but it was not intended behaviour. It was treated as a bug because it could lead to distortions and was removed, read more about it here: Proportional Editing: 'Connected Only' option can cause distortions depending on topology

Legend! Thank you so much for the info!
